# How to move form field to new line with bootstrap grid?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-bootstrap3

I am using [django-bootstrap3 form](http://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags.html#bootstrap-field) that I would like to alter a little bit. This is code I am using:

```
<div class="row">
  {% for field in form %}
    {% bootstrap_field field form_group_class='col-md-6 form-group label-floating' %}
    {% if field.name == 'field3' %}
      <!-- what should I add here -->
    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

It creates two columns of form fields, since there is `col-md-6`. I would like to move field from second column to new line. How can I do this in my code?

```
field1     field2
field3     field4
field5     field6
```

and I want fields to be ordered like this:

```
field1     field2
field3     
field4     field5
field6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice and easy, just use col-md-6 as you already have for field 1 and field 2, but for field 3 use col-md-6 and col-md-offset-6.

So it needs to be as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-6"></div><div class="col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"></div><div class="col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6"></div>
```

Use CSS to change the offset direction:

```
.col-md-offset-6 {
      margin-right: 50% !important;
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the CSS, this changes the offset to the right as oppossed to left.

Comment: Not a problem, apologies for the mistake before.

Comment: hmm, but it breaks if I resize screen. How can it be edited so it has size 12 on table/mobile?

Comment: Add the following CSS rules:

col-sm-12 (for tablet) and col-xs-12 (for mobile)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you move your if condition to be above your application of the col-md-6? I'm not familiar with django's syntax, but something like:

```
{% for field in form %}
  {% if field.name == 'field3' %}
      {% bootstrap_field field form_group_class='col-md-12 form-group label-floating' %}
  {% else %}
    {% bootstrap_field field form_group_class='col-md-6 form-group label-floating' %}  
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried that, but I want to have `field3` with size 6, not 12. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Why do you want it to have col-md-6 and yet occupy a whole row?

Comment: to separate fields logically. Like first 3 fields should be together and then another 3 as well.